# Как получить данные JSON с сервера?

Tags: php, javascript, json

У меня есть файл `data.json` с данными. Я запросил данные на JS через `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'data.json');

    request.send();

request.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if( request.readyState === 4 ) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
};
```

Как мне получить данные из `data.json`?

Какой скрипт на php нужен чтобы вернуть данные из файла `data.json` клиенту?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На PHP нужен для примера такой скрипт, чтобы вернуть данные в виде JSON клиенту:

**Код PHP-сервера:**

```
<?php
    // название файла: getColorRGB.php
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    //Получаем составляющие цвета (red, green, blue)
    $col = new stdClass();
    $col->r = 128;
    $col->g = 0;
    $col->b = 255;

    //Выводим JSON для AJAX-запрса:
    echo json_encode($col);
?>
```

Или же, если нужно вернуть именно `data.json`, то код такой:

```
<?php
    // название файла: getColorRGB.php
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    $json = file_get_contents("data.json");
    //Выводим JSON для AJAX-запрса:
    echo json_decode($json);
?>
```

Но тогда на клиенте обращение к `JSON`-объекту должно быть в соответствии с вашими данными в `data.json`.

**[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)** — Возвращает JSON-представление данных.

**Код клиента для чтения такой:**

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'getColorRGB.php', true);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
        var color = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById('color').innerHTML = color.r + ', ' + color.g + ', ' + color.b;
    }
};
```

Comment: А можно OpenServer настроить так, чтобы он JSON возвращал без php скриптов?

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS, я не знаком с OpenServer. Но настроить можно. Советую обратиться к ним на форум с этим вопросом. https://ospanel.io/forum/